# how to determine end of php sqlsrv_fetch_array

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm not a php guy but have to code a page so I'm struggling a bit.  I have the following code getting records from a mysql database.

```
$results = db::query("select ColorHex, ColorUseDescription from Website_Color where BuildId=(?)", array($id));

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)){
    echo '{';
    echo    '"ColorHex":'.json_encode($row["ColorHex"]).',';
    echo    '"ColorUseDescription":'.json_encode($row["ColorUseDescription"]);
    echo '},';
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I need to not have the last echo line present when I'm on the last record.  I'm writing a json string to the page, so having a trailing comma at the end of this array is throwing off the json parser.

How can I get a count of the number of records returned so I can wrap that last echo in an if statement?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`sqlsrv-num-rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php) will tell you beforehand how many rows are in the result set.